# Check if element in an array is of type int

Tags: c, integer, fgets

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char arr[20];

    fgets(arr, sizeof(arr), stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != /* int */)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to loop through an array and if in the array there is anything other than a number, I want to "do something."

Is it possible to check if the element in the array is a number?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `isdigit` from `<ctype.h>`

Comment: @user3386109 Is there a way to check if the array contains anything other than an int?

Comment: `isdigit` is used to check a single character. So you need to write a loop that checks each character. If `isdigit` returns false for any character, then the array contains one or more characters that are not digits. Note that you need to stop the loop when it reaches the newline character `'\n'` or the nul character `'\0'` because those are definitely not digits.

Comment: What do you mean by “of type int”?  All of the elements are integers.  Do you perhaps mean to check if they are characters of digits?

Comment: Every element of the array is of type `char`, not `int`. You're trying to do something other than checking whether the elements are of type `int`.  Perhaps you want to check whether the characters are decimal digits? Or perhaps you're looking for sequences of characters like `"123"` that could represent an `int` value? If you update your question with some examples, a line of text and what you're looking for in it, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number or type int (as in the title)?

You have a string of length 20. How do you define a number? A sequence of digits? This loops through the array and finds isolated digits, then uses `atoi()` and `atof()` to convert.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void main(void)
{
    char arr[20];

    fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin);

    printf("STRING: %s\n", arr);

    for (int i = 0; (arr[i]); i++)
    {
            if (isdigit(arr[i]))
                printf("Digit: %c\n", arr[i]);
            else
                printf("%c\n", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("atoi: %d\n", atoi(arr));
    printf("atof: %f\n", atof(arr));

}
```

Output:

```
STRING: -3.1411isnegpi

-
Digit: 3
.
Digit: 1
Digit: 4
Digit: 1
Digit: 1
i
s
n
e
g
p
i


atoi: -3
atof: -3.141100
```

And also:

```
STRING: 1e22

Digit: 1
e
Digit: 2
Digit: 2


atoi: 1
atof: 10000000000000000000000.000000
```

Checking for digits in a string  is trivial, but to extract "numbers" is not. Is "1e22" numbers 1 and 22? Is "abc10" a number?